# React Native : Aligning images side by side on one line with a dynamic number of images

Tags: react-native, icons, react-native-flatlist, react-native-listview, react-native-flexbox

I am new to react native and I am trying to implement this view :

[The view I try to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c87B0.png)

The first difficulty I encounter is to show the little green circles side by side.

The second comes from the fact that the number of little green circles is not constant... This number comes from my API. I would like to show from 2 to 6 little green circles depending on the number sent by my API (note that I know how to retrieve this information from my API, my problem is how to implement the View).

Thank you very much for you help...

Comment: well, show us the code so.

Comment: <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>{greenCirclesArray.map( unneededItem => <GreenCircle />}</View> is one solution. Could also use a FlatList, have a function instead of the map that uses a for loop to push all the <GreenCircle /> components into an array and then just have that array between the {}, etc. What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Hi @HBSKan Thanks so much for your help. I realize now that it was not so difficult... But you know was it is to start in a new language... Sometimes we look too far and we forget the basics! I warmly thank you for your rapid and accurate answer.

Comment: No worries. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @HBSKan, the answer is:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>{this.state.InfoFromApi.logo_tab.map( elem => 
  <Image key={elem.type} style = {styles.logo} source={require('../assets/green_circles.png')} />
)}</View>
```

Thanks to him!